# How to configure OpenLDAP dn in php?

Tags: php, openldap

Just learned the OpenLDAP by today and I want to integrate with the PHP. What I did is installing the OpenLDAP this is my structure looks like:

[LDAP Structure Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/8d9ibo)

Than, I want to integrate this LDAP within the PHP, but I don't know how to get the information for this configuration (tried with this with no luck):

```
protected $baseDn = "dc=maxcrc,dc=com";
protected $dn = "cn=Manager,ou=group,o=accounts,dc=maxcrc,dc=com";
protected $groupOU = "ou=group";
protected $peopleOU = "ou=People";
protected $peopleOU = "ou=People";
```

Can somebody expertise in this help me? this is my full code for ldapconnection

```
 <?php
include_once('settings.php');

class LDAP_Connector {
    protected $baseDn = "dc=maxcrc,dc=com";

    // Distinguished name for the admin.
    protected $dn = "cn=Manager,ou=group,o=accounts,dc=maxcrc,dc=com";

    // The ou of groups.
    protected $groupOU = "ou=group";

    // The ou of people.
    protected $peopleOU = "ou=People";

    protected $ldapconn;

    public function __construct() {
        global $ldapHost, $ldapPort, $ldapUser, $ldapPassword;

        message("Creating LDAP connector");
        $this->ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapHost, $ldapPort);
        if ($this->ldapconn) {
            message("LDAP Connected - ".$this->ldapconn);
        }
        else {
            message("LDAP failed to connect");
        }
    }

    public function authenticate($username, $password) {
        $r = false;
        global $ldapHost, $ldapPort, $ldapUser, $ldapPassword;

        if ($this->ldapconn) {
            $bind = ldap_bind($this->ldapconn, $this->dn, $ldapPassword);
            if ($bind) {
                //$uid = $ldapUser;
                $uid = $username;

                // Filter on the uid.
                $filter = "(mail=". $uid . ")";

                // Return the userPassword.
                $attr = array("userpassword","rpDisabledState");

                // Get the record for the user.
                $result = ldap_search($this->ldapconn, $this->peopleOU . "," . $this->baseDn, $filter, $attr);

                //message( "result = ".print_r($result, true) );

                $entries = ldap_get_entries($this->ldapconn, $result);
                //message( print_r($entries, true));

                $ldapEncodedPW = "{SHA}".base64_encode(pack("H*", $password));

                $userDisabled = $entries[0]["rpdisabledstate"][0];
                message("User ".$username." state is ".$userDisabled);

                if ($userDisabled) {
                    message("username ".$username." is disabled ");
                }

                if ($entries[0]["userpassword"][0]==$ldapEncodedPW && !$userDisabled) {
                    $r = true;
                }
                else {
                    message("Passwords do not match or the account has been disabled.");
                    message("Password (provided) = ".$ldapEncodedPW);
                    message("Password (ldap)     = ".$entries[0]["userpassword"][0]);

                }
            }
        }
        return $r;
    }
}
?>
```

Hope someone can help me with this, I stacked a week for this stuf :((

Regards,
T